# Angular 11 Ngxs-Storage-Plugin restore Dates

Tags: angular, ngxs

I'm trying to transition from NgRx to NGXS in my Angular project and i was wondering if there is any way to restore dates with the Ngxs-Storage-Plugin like the library [ngrx-store-localstorage](https://github.com/btroncone/ngrx-store-localstorage) for NgRx does or do i have to do it manually in the `afterDeserialize` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in way for the storage plugin to know what is a date and what's a string/number. You're best bet would be to just use the [Serialization Interceptors](https://www.ngxs.io/plugins/storage#serialization-interceptors) or create a [Custom Storage Engine](https://www.ngxs.io/plugins/storage#serialization-interceptors).
Under the hood the default storage engine just uses `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify`

Comment: Thank you, for your help, i just use the interceptors for now, so far it is working! :)